# Find password protected files on macbook pro High Sierra

Tags: macos, finder, password, spotlight, search

Is it possible to search for password protected Microsoft office (word or excel) files? I have forgotten some passwords and am trying to recover them. I noticed a password protected file is not 'locked' per se, it just has a lock symbol for preview. Is there something that can be put into the Terminal? I tried finder security, it does NOT work at all.
Thank you
[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mdfind` in Terminal like so:

```
mdfind "kMDItemSecurityMethod == 'Password Encrypted'"
```

It will print all the files that are password encrypted.

Comment: On Monterey, lists a lot of pdf files but not the password-protected Word or Excel files.

Comment: Ok I didn't know that I have no Word nor Excel installed on my machine, so I can't check if those files have anything stored in their metadata. Please run `mdls FILE_TO_CHECK.doc` and see if there's anything related to password protection.

Comment: Sadly, I don't think a Spotlight search (either in Finder or `mdfind`) can work, because (by experiment) the Spotlight Importer for Word (and I assume Excel) does not populate any suitable Spotlight metadata related to password-protection.